# Suggestion on linked and related

Tags: feature-request, linked-questions, related-questions

I have these two suggestions,

1. In both the tabs, indicate if the question are closed. Sometimes, I open a question to see that it is a poor question which is closed.
2. Don't repeat the questions which come in linked in related.

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks for the digging, I've done the actual closure.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow, I wasn't completely sure it was covered because one question is only about [duplicate] and its original claims something (closed questions not shown) which I'm not sure is up to date.